# Sql server query equivalent in LINQ

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I am trying to convert the following query in LINQ, tried different links but no luck so far. Please help with below:

```
SELECT T.TASKID, 
    T.TITLE, 
    T.DESCRIPTION, 
    T.DEADLINE, 
    T.CREATEDON,
   (SELECT EMAIL FROM ASPNETUSERS WHERE ID = T.CREATEDBYUSERID) AS INITIATEDBY
FROM TBL_TASKMEMBERS AS M   
INNER JOIN TBL_TASKS AS T ON M.TASKID = T.TASKID
INNER JOIN ASPNETUSERS AS U ON M.USERID = U.ID
WHERE m.UserId = '95d2f49c-0ae6-4571-9d7b-1c498ad0bfac'
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Linq in Code or with Linq-extensions?

Comment: Please share your best unsuccessful attempt, and describe what happened when you tried it. Among other things, this will provide the names of your fields and tables.

Comment: I am working on a C# project, asp.net Identity and trying to use LINQ  to query DB

Comment: entity framework or something else? what do your data classes look like?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var result =
from member in TBL_TASKMEMBERS 
join task in TBL_TASKS on member.TASKID equals task.TASKID
join user in ASPNETUSERS on user.ID equals member.USERID
join usermail in ASPNETUSERS on usermail.ID equals task.CREATEDBYUSERID
where member.UserId = '95d2f49c-0ae6-4571-9d7b-1c498ad0bfac'
select new { TASKID = task.TASKID, TITLE = task.TITLE, DESCRIPTION = taks.DESCRIPTION, DEADLINE = task.DEADLINE, CREATEDON = task.CREATEDON, INITIATEDBY = usermail.EMAIL };
```

Comment: Thank you, gives me an idea.